# How to perform prolonged animations

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, animation, video

I'm wondering how to perform prolonged animations in Objective-C. An example of what i'm looking to implement would be the following:

http://vimeo.com/38514156

The way I have done this before is using the following code:

```
NSArray *imgArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"car1.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"car2.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"car3.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"car4.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"car5.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"car6.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"car7.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"car8.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"car9.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"car10.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"car11.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"car12.png"],
                     nil];

imgCar.animationImages = imgArray;
imgCar.animationDuration = 0.8;
imgCar.animationRepeatCount = 0; //0 means infinite
[imgCar startAnimating];
```

I'm wondering if there a better way to do something like the video i posted above? If the animation is going on for about 45 seconds I'm guessing i would need a few hundred images - which seems like it probably won't be just intensive, but also be quite a big application.

Comment: Why don't you play a pre-made video?

Comment: I guess that's what i'm wondering - would that be the best way to it? The designer will probably be doing the video with Flash. Is there a way to export this to a suitable video type? Also, what is the ideal video type to play on iOS?

Comment: Well, if you have a 45 second animation, say 2 frames per second it'll be 90 images to add one by one. I think it's better to have a single video (even if I don't know exactly how the result will look like and if it'll fit your needs). You can use `MPMoviePlayerController` to play the video, however there are only few supported formats (.mov, .mp4, .mpv, and .3gp). I actually don't know how you can convert Flash to mp4, but I guess it's possible in some ways.

Comment: Surely it's the designers job to provide assets in a workable format?

Comment: Yes it is, but it's my job to request the workable format.

Comment: iOS does not support a lossless video format by default, so if you encode with h.264 then the video can be played back but you may have issues with colors and font renderings or other sharp edges. You can use a 3rd party extension to support directly converting lossless Quicktime Animation codec .mov to a playable iOS format (my library is called AVAnimator). But, whatever you do make sure that you do not use the UIView.animationImages as it will consume all app memory and crash your device with any kind of long animation.